# Calculate image position

Tags: c++, image, position, coordinates

I have a problem to calculate position for a image to render on screen.

**Example**:

I have an image `378x51` and screen is `1024x768`.

I know to calculate image on center is:

> ```
> screen.x / 2 - image.x / 2
>
> screen.y / 2 - image.y / 2
> ```

My problem is calculate with some `float` to render in determined coordinate.

**Example**:

```
float screenPosX = 0.3

float screenPoY = 0.4
```

<sub>*assuming that the maximum value of the float is 1.0f*</sub>

I need to render current image using these coordinates.

Comment: image.left=screen.width * screenPosX-image.w/2; image.top=screen.heigh * screenPosY-image.h/2

Comment: @feech Answers go down there vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv

Comment: Thanks @feech. I have only a problem, in original version using `1920 screen`, with image `width 378` and using float `pos 0.3f`, coordinate X is `756`.  Someone have idea how I can get this?